# How to convert many mp3 files to wav files in python

Tags: python, r

I know with the help of ffmpeg, we can convert an mp3 to wav file. But is there any code or function for automating the process. Which means I have many mp3 files, Instead of manually converting each and every file, is there any other option to convert all the mp3 files to wav files in a particular folder?

Comment: Why would you want to convert an MP3 to a WAV file? You just get a bigger file with the same sound quality!

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place to have people do all your work for you. See: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

Install the module **pydub**

```
pip install pydub
```

Install **ffmpeg**

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Use the below code to convert all the mp3 files

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

# files                                                                         
src_folder = "/home/user/Music/mp3"
dst_folder = "/home/user/Music/wav"

#get all music file
files = os.listdir(src_folder)
for name in files:
    #name of the file                                                           
    wav_name = name.replace(".mp3", "")
    try:
        # convert wav to mp3 
        sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("{}/{}".format(src_folder, name))
        sound.export("{}/{}".format(dst_folder, wav_name), format="wav")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

You can find more detailed information here - [Link](https://pythonbasics.org/convert-mp3-to-wav/)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. This code works and it solved my problem.